# Can't seem to retrieve session value or control value on .aspx page javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Wonder if anyone can help as im really stuck on a problem i'm having

Using vb.net I have a web application with several .aspx pages.

on one of my aspx pages I have a javascript function that i want to retrieve a pdf path from a session value i set within code behind. After searching the web everywhere seems to say use something like the following

var pdf_link = '<%=Session["pdfpath"].ToString() %>';

here is the javascript function:

```
                function showmodal() {
                var pdf_link = '<%=Session["pdfpath"].ToString() %>';
                var iframe = '<div class="iframe-container"><iframe src="' + pdf_link + '"></iframe></div>'
                $.createModal({
                    title: 'PDF Preview',
                    message: iframe,
                    closeButton: true,
                    scrollable: false
                });
            }
```

to get the value but i get an error message before i can even compile  'Identifier Expected' and it highlights between the [" as being the problem area. i just can't get this to work what am i doing wrong.

Also because i couldn't workout what was wrong with the above i have tried saving the value i want into a hidden field and tried to access that using the following

document.getElementById("PdfPathHiddenField").value

but that just returns null all the time. I just can't seem to access anything within my javascript function.

What i also see as odd is for instance when debugging i have say page1.aspx and page2.aspx. From page1.aspx in code behind on a button click i use

Response.Redirect("~/page2.aspx")

When I have stopped the debugger within my javascript function on page2.aspx to retrieve the value i notice that the tab with the code where the debugger has stopped for page2.aspx is titled page1[Dynamic] but it is the correct source from page2.aspx not page1.aspx really confused as shouldn't it say page2[Dynamic] on that - is this why i maybe can't seem to access any controls as it thinks it's elsewhere ???? Help

Thanks in advance any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did You add `runat="server"` for that hidden field?

Comment: hi thanks for the reply my hidden field is set with runat="server". What i have  also tried now is setting a starting value and when i reference the field i get that value but i can't seem to get the updated value that has been set in code behind. any ideas thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In **VB.NET** arrays have parentessis, `Session("pdfpath").ToString()`, in C# or javascript you can use square brackets, but not in VB.

PS: Remeber to mark this an answer if it's a solution for your problem

Comment: thanks for the response. I have edited my original post to include my javascript function in full where i'm having the problem. Your suggestion is it not for code behind and not my javascript function? Thanks in advance

Comment: i have replaced my line with var pdf_link =  '<%=Session("pdfpath")%>'; but when debugging the line ends up just reading                 function showmodal() {
                    debugger;
                    var pdf_link = ''; so no value what so ever comes through?